# [JavaScript]¿Cómo puedo hacer para seleccionar un elemento que aun no se ha cargado en el DOM sin usar setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero selccionar un input de texto y contraseña pero al parecer en la página donde estoy trabajando demora unos segundos (a veces inmediato, a veces 1 o 2s) en cargar esos elementos por lo que usar un setTimeout no seria muy util.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Para que las preguntas sean bien recibidas debes mostrar lo que has intentado. Ello motiva a la comunidad para ofrecer respuestas. Usa `$(document).ready()` este evento ocurre cuando el DOM ha terminado de cargarse.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    //seleccionas tus input
    $('input[type=text]');
    $('input[type=password]');
    
});

//equivalente (otra forma de escribirla, el efecto es el mismo)
$(function(){
    
    //seleccionas tus input
    $('input[type=text]');
    $('input[type=password]');
    
});
```

`$(document).ready()` y su equivalente esta indicando que cuando toda la pagina este lista (cargada) realice todas funciones y eventos definidos en su cuerpo.

Answer (score 0):

En Jquery deberías usar el `$document.ready()`que eso lo que hará es ejecutar todo lo que este entre parentesis cuando la página esté lista.

[Aquí](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) te dejo más información para que puedas investigar